# SharePoint 2013: Adding old Access Datasheet View

Tags: 2013, list-view, datasheet

We have migrated a lot of sites from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013.

I observed a very unique behaviour,  if my SharePoint 2007 list contained a Access Datasheet view,  they remain the same and I see Access based Datasheet view.

However I dont have any way of creating the datasheet view in the old way.  It uses Quick Edit view which is pretty slow in Internet Explorer.

Do we have any workaround through which I can create the datasheet view in the old access way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer on using the good old SP2010 Datasheet view in SharePoint 2013, we've created a free solution:

http://www.kwizcom.com/free-downloads/datasheet-view-for-sharepoint-2013/

Note: I work for this company.

Answer (score 0):

On the SharePoint 2013 site, instead of Quick Edit view,  I needed to show the SharePoint list in the datasheet view like 2010/2007. After trying several different settings I figured, If the site is created using the Publishing Site Template, the old datasheet view is still available.

If the site is created using Team Site template, enabling publishing feature will not help. We will need to manage with Quick Edit.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate this in an on-premises 2013 environment.